# MVC Schema Compare not detecting the changed data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

When I use `schema compare` in Visual Studio it doesn't detect the information that I have added to my database. Is schema compare only for comparing the tables and their relationships ? If yes, how can I add my data from the `SQL Server database` to my `SQL Database Project` in MVC?

Comment: No, you can't. In schema compare you can't add data from your DB to DB Project in MVC. You can only compare and update tables, relationships, views, etc from here to there and vice versa.

Comment: @BasantaMatia so is there any option that I can use from Visual Studio so that in adds in the data from the database inside my SQL Database Project ?